# Regex matching stucks my JVM

Tags: java, regex, loops

I had some problems with JBehave library and they came down to regex stucking my JRE with CPU work.

The expression is `(.*?)?(\{((.*?)(\|)?)*?\})(.*)` and I'm matching it against `create entity of type $entityType {set properties $propertyNames to values $propertyValues` - notice the unclosed curly bracket.

Is there a way to optimize the above expression or work around it gracefully?

Comment: I do not see much difference with `.*\{.*\}.*`. If you need special elements in the repetitions, using `find`, one would search a sub-expression.

Comment: What is the goal of your regex?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, It's not really mine, I found it in the code of JBehave, and it tries to extract parameters out of possible pattern.

Comment: @Vic: please give some example strings with the result you hope

Comment: It seems like the unclosed bracket is to blame, without it or when its closed the expression is evaluated quickly

Comment: This is normal, see my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern that do the same thing (with the same captures):

```
([^\n{]*+)(\{(([^|}]++)(\|)?+)*+\})([^\n]*+)
```

The idea here is to fail as fast as possible. That's why i have replaced lazy quantifiers by constraining character classes with possessive quantifiers.

But since you don't give the final goal of this, I can't give you a better pattern.

Comment: You might want to change `++` to `+` and `*+` to `*`, but otherwise it's a good approach.

Comment: with the change you suggest the result will be slower. The goal here is to not allow the re engine to backtrack

Comment: Oh, they're the non-backtracking versions? I always forget those. On the other hand, with appropriate sets the engine will be able to figure out for itself that it doesn't need to backtrack at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is not that it loops, it is that it is far from being fail-fast. The cause is this part:

```
((.*?)(\|)?)*?
```

What is supposed to be matched by the first `*?` and the second one? In case of failure, the regex engine has to backtract to try *all* combinations. (well, not DFA engines, but the Java regex engine is NFA)

Now, you need to tell what this regex is supposed to match so that a sane regex can be written.

And this is why lazy quantifiers suck, by the way.

Comment: Stack-based engines can get the same behavior with greedy REs, but require slightly different way to get it to happen. Automata-theoretic approaches have different problems though (for one thing, they're horrendous to debug!)